# Take a screenshot of a URL programmatically in Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I would like to take a screenshot of a rendered webpage in Google App Engine. Any suggestions on the best way I can accomplish this? Any Java libraries that I can programmatically render a page to a JPG or PNG?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would really need a complete render engine for this to work, and I doubt any of them would run on Google App Engine. I think it would be best to use an external API such as [thumbalizr](http://www.thumbalizr.com/). Also have a look at [BrowserShots](http://www.browsershots.org/).

Answer (score 1):

i would use a public webservice for that. something like [girafa](http://www.girafa.com/). if you need shots for all browsers [browsershots](http://browsershots.org) is the one for you.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a bit late but might be helpful for anyone who is still looking for an answer as it comes first in Google search results.

With Google App Engine support for Node.js, it is possible to take screenshots using headless chrome with puppeteer.

The Google team has put down the guide on the link below:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/using-headless-chrome-with-puppeteer

Answer (score 0):

Try whether you can use [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) in GAE. It contains a browser control which you can render to. I've posted an answer here with some code how to do save the content of the browser widget as a PNG but I can't find it anymore.